# How do I access Linux commands from Wine?

Tags: wine

How can I use wine cmd to access ubuntu terminal or export commands from wine cmd or IPtables for instance or program a software via vb6 that uses iptables in ubuntu or run sh files via vb6 software or batch file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, for REALLY good security reasons, this would not be possible. What would be your purpose here?

Comment: I'm a windows software programmer so I wanna secure ma network using Ubuntu IPtables as its easy and effective but I want to run sh files from wine cmd or sth like dat so I push commands from ma software to terminal

Comment: The problem here is that I see no reason for using wine. Unless all you know is Visual Basic that is. Don't use wine, learn C, perl or python would be how I would do it :D Thing is: how to code in WINE to me is too much Windows related. And even then it is in a crippled Windows environment. Even using vBox with windows in it is probably better.

Comment: @Matthew: if you want to run secure, ditch Windows and run pure Ubuntu.  If you want to be reasonably safe, secure Windows and ditch Ubuntu but don't try to run Windows under Ubuntu: you're increasing your error rate and decreasing your system security.

Comment: I also have access databases already with data that are integrated with previous versions of the software ...this is an upgrade! ...isnt there a way may be using bat file first then dat runs a sh file or php file that opens and pushes commands to terminal or so....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6006617/2072269?

Comment: Tried running IPtable commands from php and its not working ...ls and other simple commands work but not IPtables ...why?? with execute('Iptables...............') then run it through xampp but not working??

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's better to say "no" and this is one of these cases... What you're trying to do is to put a secure front-end over an insecure back-end.

- Windows comes from a heritage of a single-user, single-tasking OS. (DOS)
- Linux comes from a heritage of a multi-user, multi-tasking OS (Unix)

For the former, security was an afterthought, (though it has come a long way) and the latter, security was *by design*.

What you're trying to do is to secure an insecure system by opening up the things on the secure system it's running on, therefore [propagating errors](http://reference.wolfram.com/applications/eda/ExperimentalErrorsAndErrorAnalysis.html) instead of containing them.

To put this in human terms: *you're putting in a firewall and then opening up too many ports.*

**Don't do it!**

<sub>Instead, secure Ubuntu more instead of less...</sub>

Comment: Windows hasn't been built on top of a single-user OS for over a decade and a half. Windows XP ran on top of NT.

Comment: Correct, but what OP is trying to do is still a bad idea... @DamianYerrick

Answer (score 0):

Been there, done that. It's actually not that hard to break out of the wine sandbox. A couple dozen lines of assembly code can invoke the vfork()/exec() pathway to completely defeat the sandbox wrapper.

However you want to run iptables. iptables only works as root. The wine documentation [[1]](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Should_I_run_Wine_as_root.3F) says don't run wine as root. There was an infamous case where a bug lurked for half a decade that was trying to write to /dev/sda and quietly failing; right up until the day somebody ran something as root that enumerated drives. Oops.